# Ember.js Get model length without call 'findAll()'

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I find a method for get model length.

I tried to use findAll method.

```

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
      console.log("CHECK MODEL");
      let texts = this.store.findAll('text');
    }
});
```

```

why return 0?

How can I get a model length with out using findAll method?

Comment: Checking model length in model - before model is defined? O.O

Comment: @DanielKmak yes, I need check model length before set model in route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
      console.log("CHECK MODEL");
      let textsPromise = this.store.findAll('text');
      textsPromise.then(loadedTexts => {
         let modelLength = loadedTexts.get('length');
         console.log('Length is: ' + modelLength);
      });
      return textsPromise;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you :) I'll try this.